# Alphabetical comparing two string in WHERE

Tags: sql, oracle

i have Oracle DB and there table named Books.

Books structure:

```
id_book (FK)
name
year
```

And my task is to find pairs of books, which was published in same year. Let the films in pairs be in alphabetical order. So there will be only

```
first_name Hobit
second_name The Lord of the Rings
```

And not this:

```
first_name The Lord of the Rings
second_name Hobit
```

And year will be same, for example 2002.

My wrong solution:

```
SELECT B1.name, B2.name, B1.year FROM Books B1, Books B2
WHERE B1.year = B2.year
AND B1.id_book != B2.id_book
GROUP BY B1.name, B2.name, B1.year HAVING LOWER(B1.name) <= LOWER(B2.name)
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Show us some more sample data, and also the expected result.

Comment: It is in school test, so i know only this information, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

You are close to the solution.

1) `group by` is not required

2) instead on !=   and <=  filters use: `a.name < b.name`

With such test data

```
select * from books 
order by year, name;

NAME                        YEAR
--------------------- ----------
Hobit                       2002
OMG Book                    2002
The Lord of the Rings       2002
Do Not Readme Book          2003
```

This is the query

```
select a.name first_name, b.name second_name
from books a
join books b
on a.year = b.year
where a.name < b.name
order by 1,2;

FIRST_NAME            SECOND_NAME          
--------------------- ---------------------
Hobit                 OMG Book             
Hobit                 The Lord of the Rings
OMG Book              The Lord of the Rings
```

You may gather extra points in your *school test* by mentioning that this query will not scale well.

For `n` books in a sample year you get `n * (n-1) / 2` records in the result set.